# order by clause is breaking Anorm select query in Play 2.1.2

Tags: mysql, anorm

I have the following code in Play 2.1.2

```
def list(startDate:String, endDate:String,  page:Option[Int], pageSize:Option[Int] ) = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
        val c = SQL("""
              select 
                employeeId,
                CertType, 
                ct.name, 
                applicable,
                due,
                year(due) as yeardue,   month(due) as monthdue, day(due) as daydue, 
                year(completed),     month(completed),     day(completed), 
                year(last),       month(last),       day(last), 
                status 
              from cert 
              join certtype ct on CertType=ct.code
              where due<{endDate} and due>{startDate} and CertType not in (500,600)
              order by due
            """ 
          )
          .on('index -> page, 'pageSize -> pageSize , 'startDate -> startDate, 'endDate->endDate)().collect{
            case Row(  
                  employeeId:Long,
                  certType:Int, 
                  name:String, 
                  applicable:Int,
                  Some(due:java.sql.Date),
                  Some(yeardue:Long),      Some(monthdue:Long),     Some(daydue:Long),
                  Some(yearcompleted:Long),  Some(monthcompleted:Long),   Some(daycompleted:Long),
                  Some(yearlast:Long),    Some(monthlast:Long),     Some(daylast:Long),
                  status:Long) =>
                  Reminder(
                      employeeId, 
                      certType, 
                      name,  
                      if (applicable>0) true else false, 
                      makeDate(yeardue,    monthdue,    daydue),  
                      makeDate(yearcompleted,  monthcompleted,  daycompleted),  
                      makeDate(yearlast,    monthlast,    daylast),  
                      status);
        }
        c.toList
    }
}
```

The only way this works is if I remove the 'order by' clause.
Order by will work only with a string field like ct.name.
Otherwise, the list is empty.

I have no error messages from this, just a blank list.

Comment: Actually ordering in code is usually preferred to ordering in DB from the point of efficiency. Also, AFAIK in SQL order by works for dates as well. May be the issue in Anorm? Could you use Slick instead? Or just don't do ordering in DB. Also, `due between startDate and endDate` is slightly more efficient as well.

Comment: Hmm... not sure about ordering in code being more efficient, but thanks for the tip on using 'between' for date range.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this works now and I'm not sure why .

Here's the working version:

```
def list(startDate:String, endDate:String,  page:Option[Int], pageSize:Option[Int] ) = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
        val c = SQL("""
                        select 
                            employeeId,
                            CertType, 
                            ct.name, 
                            applicable,
                            due,
                            completed,
                            last,
                            status 
                        from cert 
                        join certtype ct on CertType=ct.code
                        where due between {startDate} and {endDate} and CertType not in (500,600)
                        order by due
                    """ 
            )
            .on('index -> page, 'pageSize -> pageSize , 'startDate -> startDate, 'endDate->endDate)().collect{
                case Row(   
                            employeeId:Long,
                            certType:Int, 
                            name:String, 
                            applicable:Int,
                            Some(due:java.sql.Date),        // optional to handle potential null value
                            Some(completed:java.sql.Date),  // optional to handle potential null value
                            last:java.sql.Date,             // this is probably required to NOT be optional since it is a PK in the schema (?)
                            status:Long) =>
                    Reminder(
                            employeeId, 
                            certType, 
                            name,  
                            if (applicable>0) true else false, 
                            new DateTime(due.       getTime()).toString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                            new DateTime(completed. getTime()).toString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                            new DateTime(last.      getTime()).toString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                            status);
        }
      c.toList
    }
  }
```